# link error when using random_device from boost

Tags: c++, boost, clang++

I have installed on `MacOSX 10.15` boost using brew, all working fine, beside random_device.

This is what i have written:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/random/mersenne_twister.hpp>
#include <boost/random/discrete_distribution.hpp>
#include <boost/random/random_device.hpp>

int main() {
    boost::random::random_device rand_dev;
    boost::mt19937 gen(rand_dev());
    double probabilities[]{0, 0.99, 0.01, 0};
    boost::random::discrete_distribution<> dist(probabilities);
    std::cout << dist(gen);

    return 0;
}
```

And this is what i have got from compiler:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>
> "boost::random::random_device::random_device()", referenced from:
> _main in main.cpp.o
>
> "boost::random::random_device::~random_device()", referenced from:
> _main in main.cpp.o
>
> "boost::random::random_device::operator()()", referenced from:
> _main in main.cpp.o
>
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
> invocation)

I am linking it using CMake. And also i have installed it on the `Ubuntu 18` and got same linking errors.

This is a part of my CMake:

```
find_package(Boost 1.72)  

if(Boost_FOUND)
     include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
     target_link_libraries(test_boost ${Boost_LIBRARY_DIR}) 
endif()
```

Comment: "_And this is what i have got from compiler:_" These are the errors from the linker, not compiler. How are you linking your application? Did you link with the relevant boost library?

Comment: I am linking it using CMake. And also i have installed it on the `Ubuntu 18` and got same linking errors.

This is a part of my CMake:

```find_package(Boost 1.72)

if(Boost_FOUND)
    include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    target_link_libraries(test_boost ${Boost_LIBRARY_DIR})
endif()
```

Comment: All information necessary to answer a question, must be present in the question, and not in the comments. Please [edit] your question to add said information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your CMakeLists.txt with the following code:

```
find_package(Boost 1.72 COMPONENTS random)
if(Boost_FOUND) 
    include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}) 
    target_link_libraries(test_boost ${Boost_LIBRARIES}) 
endif()
```

Answer (score 0):

Add -lboost_random to linker inputs as compiler command line argument:

```
g++  -o  test  test.cpp  -lboost_random
```

Comment: Thanks, it is now linking and compiling, but only from terminal. Maybe you know how to add flags to linker in CMake? I have added such row - `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -lboost_random")`

Comment: @dikiidog Something like `target_link_libraries(targetName -lboost_random)` where `targetName` is the name of your CMake target.

Comment: @dikiidog  You may use this pattern:  ```target_link_libraries(test  boost_random)```